# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in one host but not in another for the same applicaiton

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

We are getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" when using JQuery Autcomplete in our application. We are getting this error in one host but not in another one. Both hosts are hosting the same application with the same code.

In Chrome Console, the error details is as follows:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <           autocomplete.js:123
$.autocomplete.source.$.ajax.success               autocomplete.js:123
jQuery.Callbacks.fire                              jquery-1.7.2.js:1075
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith                     jquery-1.7.2.js:1193
done                                               jquery-1.7.2.js:7538
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback                 jquery-1.7.2.js:8324
```

Any help on this issue will be very highly regarded.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you upload the file properly? And clear the browser cache.

Comment: Look at the Javascript source as downloaded by your browser.

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your php code its is returning any space or something error message with the json object.

- Check the php code for error.
- check that you uploaded the file properly
- check that is there any other echoing from php code with your json

Comment: Thanks for given instructions but issue that the same application code is working fine in the other server.

Comment: This is the application which we get the problem on: http://heac.gov.om/digitalmap/index.php?lng=eng. 1- Search for"HEAC Center" 2- Click on the marker that appears on the map and click the "Get Direction" link so a panel shall be shown in the left side  3- In the Direction panel, select "Related Locations" at END and an autocomplete text box shall be displayed. Starting to type a value in this text box is not giving autocomplete list and the mentioned error above is shown in the Chrome Console errors list. We don't get this issue in the app hosted at: http://dgulf.net/hei/index.php?lng=eng

Comment: @user That does not matter. Figure out why it's not working on *this* server. For that, first figure out what exactly is wrong on this server. Judging by the error message, there's a syntax error in a Javascript file. So the first step is to look at that Javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

Change your autcomplete_min_.js (replace with jquery-ui.js)